# Send message with restFB

Tags: java, restfb

I tried this is simple example in order to send message in Facebook:

```
public void testSomeMethod()
    {
        String token = "XXXXXX";
        FacebookClient facebookClient = new DefaultFacebookClient(token, Version.LATEST);


        IdMessageRecipient recipient = new IdMessageRecipient("123456");
        Message message = new Message("Just a simple text");

        SendResponse resp = facebookClient.publish("me/messages", SendResponse.class,
            Parameter.with("recipient", recipient), // the id or phone recipient
            Parameter.with("message", message)); // one of the messages from above
    }
```

But I get error

```
com.restfb.exception.FacebookGraphException: Received Facebook error response of type GraphMethodException: Unsupported post request. Object with ID 'me' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api (code 100, subcode null)
    at com.facebook.impl.FacebookImplTest.testSomeMethod(FacebookImplTest.java:57)
```

Can you propose some solution?

Comment: What access token do you use? Is the `recipient ID` received via the messenger platform webhook?

Comment: I use the access token from facebook developer web site.

Comment: You need the page access token from your Facebook App Messenger Section, because you try to send a chatbot message.

Comment: ok, is this Java code correct?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem two hour ago :)  Use "*{conversation_id}/messages*" instead of "*me/messages*". You can get *conversation_id* using the following code:

```
Connection<Conversation> conversations = pageClient.fetchConnection("me/conversations", Conversation.class);
    for (List<Conversation> conversationPage : conversations) {
        for (Conversation conversation : conversationPage) {
            String id = conversation.getId();   //use this conversation_id
            Connection<Message> messages = pageClient.fetchConnection(id + "/messages", Message.class, Parameter.with("fields", "message,created_time,from,id"));
            messages.forEach(s -> s.forEach(k -> System.out.println(k.getFrom() + " " + k.getId() + " " + k.getMessage() + " " + k.getSubject() + " ")));
        }
    }
```

The following code works properly for me:

```
FacebookClient pageClient = new DefaultFacebookClient(pageAccessToken, Version.VERSION_2_6);
    IdMessageRecipient recipient = new IdMessageRecipient("{user_id}");      
    String conversationId = “t_mid.14XXX.. : XXX...” ;         
    SendResponse resp = pageClient.publish(conversationId +"/messages", SendResponse.class,                
            Parameter.with("recipient", recipient),             
            Parameter.with("message", "Uraaaa!!!"));
```

Comment: I get `Caused by: com.restfb.json.JsonException: A JsonObject text must begin with '{' at character 1`